# Expo app thowing file missing error though files are actually present there

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, expo

I am using `pnpm` to create expo app. Just created `pnpm create expo-app`, installed dependencies and then run `yarn android` === `expo start --android`.

Tried shamefully-hoisting as well as moving project to location with no spaces in path but each time I get the same error.

I manually checked, all the files that are shown missing in error are actually present there.

How do I fix this?

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./node_modules\expo\AppEntry from C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\expo\AppEntry(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules\expo\AppEntry\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.72.3\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:152:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.72.3\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.72.3\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.72.3\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1196:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.72.3\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:484:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\HariC\AndroidStudioProjects\chat\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.72.3\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:435:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since android didn't work. I tried running web and I was prompted to install `@expo/webpack-config`. I installed it using `expo install @expo/webpack-config@^0.17.2` and wow… It worked!